# Creating a log file for my ffmpeg output

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, logging

I am trying to find out why my rtsp dos command using FFMPEG is 'freezing'.
Ihave been told I would have more luck on SuperUser but I have been told to produce a log file 1st.

I have looked and I have tried several things to produce this log file.

My original command line was this:

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/video_1 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=6 -qscale 0 -
```

and changed it to this:

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/video_1 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=6 -qscale 0 - > log.txt
```

But the DOS does not get beyond this:

[image]

and the log file is empty.

Please can someone advise?

Thanks

Comment: ffmpeg logs to stderr, so you have to check that. Redirect 2> to a file.

Comment: I am sure I tried that already but will give it another go when I am back. Thanks

Comment: Well, I guess it worked.

Comment: No problem :) I just wasn't sure as I didn't have a Windows instance to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ffmpeg logs to stderr, so you have to check that. Since you're already outputting to stdout, you have to redirect stderr to a file, for example:

```
ffmpeg … 2> log.txt
```

Comment: what about android?

Answer (score 2):

The `-report` flag is more what you search for debugging.

> Dump full command line and console output to a file named "program-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.log" in the current directory. This file can be useful for bug reports. It also implies "-loglevel debug".

Thus have a look at:

- `man -P "less -p report" ffmpeg`
  as well as
- `man -P "less -p loglevel" ffmpeg`.

You can change the logfile's location using the `FFREPORT` variable like so:

```
FFREPORT=file="/my/log/location/%p-%t.log":level=32 ffmpeg -i [...]
```