# Restart the process if its output unchanged in PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have this command

```
for ($i=0; $i -gt -1; $i++) {
    $path = "..."
    ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (USB Microphone)" -y -t 00:10:00 -b:a 128k $path
}
```

I need to get the current state of the last line of the command output stream, then if the line remains unchanged (staled/freezing/hanging) over 5 seconds log "warning: the program is freezing. trying to restart...", then stop the process and re-start the command.

But I wonder, is it even possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing PowerShell functions and advanced techniques, in addition to appending `2> $Log` to the `ffmpeg` command efficiently [redirects its standard error output](https://superuser.com/questions/878606/creating-a-log-file-for-my-ffmpeg-output) to a specified log file.

This approach defines the `$path`, `$log`, and `$micName` variables initially. Following that, four straightforward functions are defined and subsequently called by additional logic, using the preset variables from the beginning.

The `run-ffmpeg` function incorporates three explicitly defined parameters. Whereas, the `tail`, `check`, and `logchecks` functions utilize `$args[0]` as a placeholder to capture the first unnamed parameter passed in with their function call.

#### PowerShell

```
$path = "D:\ffmpeg\out\test.wav";
$log = "D:\ffmpeg\out\err.log";
$micName = "Microphone (USB Microphone)";
    
Function run-ffmpeg {param([string]$Path,[string]$Log,[string]$MicName)
    $ffmpegCommand = "ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio='$MicName' -y -t 00:10:00 -b:a 128k $Path 2> $Log"
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $($ffmpegCommand)" -WindowStyle Hidden;   
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4;
    logchecks $Log;
};

Function tail {Get-Content -Path $args[0] -Tail 1};
Function check {tail $args[0]};

Function logchecks {
    do {
        $checklog = check $args[0];
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
        $rechecklog = check $args[0];
    } while ($checklog -ne $rechecklog)
    
    run-ffmpeg -Path $path -Log $log -MicName $micName;  
};

logchecks $log;
```

#### Logic Support Notes

- Implemented `2> $Log` as mentioned earlier to redirect `ffmpeg` command output to a log file.
- Utilized `start-process` to execute the `ffmpeg` command within logic to ensure proper functionality.
- Used `get-content` with the `-tail 1` parameter to monitor the latest content in the log.
- Implemented a `do while` loop to periodically monitor the tail of the `ffmpeg` log file at 5-second intervals, ensuring that the content differs from the previous 5-second check.
- Incorporated `start-sleep` at strategic points to introduce delays, allowing time for subsequent checks post-execution of processes, etc.

### Supporting Resources

- [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.4)
- [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4)
- [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.4)
- [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.4)

  > `-Tail`
  >
  > Specifies the number of lines from the end of a file or other item.
  > You can use the Tail parameter name or its alias, Last. Negative
  > values cause the cmdlet to return the entire contents
- [about Do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.4)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

  > **Equality**
  >
  > - `-ne`, `-ine`, `-cne` - **not equals**

Comment: @丶 Limeー来夢 丶... This is a verified method which I tested and confirmed personally to work for meeting the expectations for a functional solution as you describe you seek. While slight adjustments may be necessary based on your specific requirements, the intention is to provide a thoroughly validated solution that should address your needs comprehensively. Please let me know if you encounter any issues, have questions, or require assistance with additional minor adjustments.

Comment: Additionally, I was playing with this but it may be overkill for your need `[timespan]$rechecklog.Split("=")[2].Split(".")[0] -eq [timespan]$checklog.Split("=")[2].Split(".")[0]`.... Just in case you were looking for a way to parse out the time part of the string. I think checking the match on the last line and the 5 second pause is more what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, it works very well so far.